# Flask virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, ubuntu-10.04, flask

I am trying to set up Flask on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.
I have install virtualenv 1.7
I am using python 2.6

I set my virtualenv and easy_install Flask
But when I check in my python import Flask fails

The Flask.egg is present in my virtualenv site-pakages.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you activated virtualenv? `$ source bin/activate`

Comment: Yes I did activated the virtualenv. If i try which easy_install i get the right path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- use lowercase:

  ```
  import flask
  ```
- “multi-version” mode might be in effect. Try `pkg_resources.require()` before importing Flask.

Answer (score 4):

type 'python' in shell and then type 'import flask', if there is no error, you can use it.

Answer (score 3):

Create a virtual environment inside your project directory:

```
virtualenv venv-name
```

Activate your virtual environment activated using:

```
source venv-name/bin/activate
```

Perform:

```
pip install flask
```

Do NOT use 'sudo' before the above command.

Check:

```
pip freeze
```

This should print out Flask==0.9 or something similar along with any other software you've installed in the virtual Python environment. Now try starting python in a terminal with the command 'python'. Type the following at the prompt to check whether you can import flask.

```
>>> from flask import Flask
>>> Flask
<class 'flask.app.Flask'>
>>>
```